# mapping a 3x3 grid in javascript

Tags: javascript

In practicing understanding arrays and how to loop through them, I wrote a function to map each row, column and two diagonals into their own key value pair.

Is there a more efficient way of looping through this? I know it's bad practice to use two for loops as it leads to high complexity if the grid were bigger than 3x3.

```js
let board = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
];

const mapper = board => {
  let
  map = {}, 
  d1 = [],
  d2 = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    let tmp = [];
    // get all rows
    map[`R${i}`] = board[i];

    // get second diagonals
    d2.push(board[i][board.length-1-i]);

    for (let j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
      // get all columns
      tmp.push(board[j][i]);

      // get first diagonals
      if (i === j) {
        d1.push(board[i][j])
      }
    }
    
    map[`C${i}`] = tmp;
  }

  map[`D1`] = d1;
  map[`D2`] = d2;

  return map;
}

console.log(mapper(board));
```

Comment: This is a question for code review, not for stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is arguably clearer, and could be imporved futher by using reduce.

```js
board = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
];

diag = 0; map = {}

board.forEach((row,r,arr) => {
 var rows = arr.length-1; 
 map['R'+r] = row; 
 map['D'+1] = map['D'+1] || [];
 map['D'+2] = map['D'+2] || [];
 map['D'+1][diag] = row[diag];
 map['D'+2][rows-diag] = row[rows-diag]
 diag++;
 row.forEach((col,c) => { 
  map['C'+c] = map['C'+c] || []; 
  map['C'+c].push(col);
  
 }); 
});

console.log(map);
```

Comment: isn't this kinda also using two for loops in a way?

Comment: Yes, but there's no alternative to reach all the parts of the board.